# How to resolve linker error for functions in ldap.h file for objective-c code

Tags: objective-c

Here I am trying LDAP for authenticating the user.
Here is some piece of my code.

## import

Here I am initializing the ldap part.

```
 LDAP          *ld;
 printf( "Connecting to host %s at port %d...\n\n", HOSTNAME, 
       PORTNUMBER );
 if ( (ld = ldap_init( HOSTNAME, PORTNUMBER )) == NULL ) {
    perror( "ldap_init" );
    return( 1 );
}
```

I am getting following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ldap_init", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Definitely I need to add the reference for -lldap library.Since I am new to this objective-c, I am facing some issues in adding library.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What platform?  What implementation of LDAP are you using?

Comment: Hi,I am using MAC lion 64 bit. I am having Xcode 4.3 in my machine.Please let me know what else you want for this issue.

Comment: Please update the tags in the question; however you haven't mentioned the implementation of LDAP you are using.

Comment: Please look into following code:#import <ldap.h>
#define HOSTNAME "localhost"
#define PORTNUMBER 389                                              // In main function                                                 LDAP          *ld;
LDAPMessage   *result, *e;
char          *dn;
int           version, rc;
if ( (ld = ldap_init( HOSTNAME, PORTNUMBER )) == NULL ) {
        perror( "ldap_init" );
        return( 1 );
    }
   Since I am a beginner in these development. I wanted to use ldap I just used it like this.Please correct me if anything is missing.